# How to list the id with getlist method in Django checkbox

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

> html file

Here I list the client and Process in the `input` tag
And select the and submit

```
{% extends 'client_pannel.html' %}
    {% block content %}

    <script>
        function postConfirm() {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this client')) {
                yourformelement.submit();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}


        <div class="breadcome-area">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="breadcome-list single-page-breadcome">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="breadcome-heading">
                                        <form role="search" class="sr-input-func">
                                            <label>{{ emp.first_name }} {{ emp.last_name }}</label>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <a href="/employee_list/"> <button type="submit"
                                            class="btn btn-info add-new">Submit</button></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="data-table-area mg-b-15">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="sparkline13-list">
                            <div class="sparkline13-graph">
                                <div class="datatable-dashv1-list custom-datatable-overright">

                                    <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true"
                                        data-show-columns="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-show-refresh="true"
                                        data-key-events="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-resizable="true"
                                        data-cookie="true" data-cookie-id-table="saveId" data-show-export="true"
                                        data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Process</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            {% for client in form %}
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="cname[]" value="{{ client.id }}">
                                                    {{ client.Name }}
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    {% for process in client.clients %}
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="process[]" value="{{ process.id }}">
                                                    {{ process.process }}<br />
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

> views file

The below code is get the selected in checkbox. The `getlist` method return nothing

```
if request.method == "POST":
        cname = request.POST.getlist('cname[]')
        print("cname", cname)
        process = request.POST.getlist('process[]')
        print("process", process)
```

Comment: Can you print the `request.POST`?

Comment: No, I am print the getlist method

Comment: please *print* `request.POST` to debug the problem...

Comment: print request.POST method retunrs these     <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['j7uUZb1yON9Zi58ZewDf4o5fskc8bjbGs0Bnm4vr27ijFt2R6mHMMllSeZRFaYXR']}>

Comment: So your data is not included in the POST. Please show the full template, including the HTML `<form>` element and submit button.

Comment: Included HTML file above, Please refer